# Solving a linear equation in one component of $\Bbb{Z}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, modules

Consider the space $X = \Bbb{Z}^3$, a $\Bbb{Z}$-module.   Let $M = \{ \sum_{i=1}^n c_i(p_i, q_i, r_i) : \sum_{i=1}^n c_i q_i = 0,$ where $p_i, q_i, r_i$ are either prime numbers or $0 \}$.  Then is $M \approx \Bbb{Z}^2$?

Clearly, $M \subset \Bbb{Z} \times 0 \times \Bbb{Z}$.  If $(x, y, z) \in M$, then clearly, summing on the 2nd component gives $y = 0$, and so... I'm having trouble seeing that you can handle the other two components independently of the second if the second is zero'd since the coefficients $c_i$ are tied up in it's sums.

For any finite $n \geq 1$ we have a system of system of 3 linear equations in $n$ unknowns in a vector $c$.  Let $x, z \in \Bbb{Z}$ be arbitrary.  We want there to always be a solution to:

$$
A c = (x, 0, z)^t
$$

Where $A$ is composed of prime numbers or $0$.  I think we just let $n \geq 3$ without loss of generality (the sums can be any finite number of terms).  Also, $A$ is allowed to vary over any primes or $0$ for each result vector $(x, y, z)^t$.  That should make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any integer can be written as linear combination of $2$ and $3$ (for instance, via $a=3a-2a$).  So, any element of $\mathbb{Z}\times 0\times\mathbb{Z}$ can be written as a linear combination of $(2,0,0)$, $(3,0,0)$, $(0,0,2)$, and $(0,0,3)$ and thus is in your $M$.

Alternatively, if you just wanted to know that $M$ was isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$, this was immediate as soon as you knew that $M$ contained two linearly independent elements (say, $(2,0,0)$ and $(0,0,2)$), since every submodule of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^m$ for some $m\leq n$.

Comment: Another question for you:  Is then $\Bbb{Z}^3 / M \approx \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, since $M=\mathbb{Z}\times 0\times\mathbb{Z}$ so the quotient can be identified with the projection onto the second coordinate.